# How to check if an element exists in exactly 3 lists from a set of 4 lists

Tags: python

I have 4 lists with a few elements each. I'm trying to make 4 more lists which will tell in how many lists each particular element shows up. So one of my lists will tell me the elements which are in all 4 of the original lists. Another will tell me which elements are in 3 out of the 4 lists. It doesn't matter how many times an element shows up in a list, just how many lists it's in.

This is doable with really long if statements, a-la

```
if ((element in list1) and (element in list2) and \
(element in list3) and not (element in list4)) or...
```

using every combination, but I'd like something cleaner and probably faster.

This is approximately what I'm working with:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8]
list2 = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8]
list3 = [1, 2, 5, 7, 8]
list4 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 8]
```

So you can see 1 and 8 are in every list, 2 shows up in three lists, etc.

This is what I want as output:

```
in_all_4_lists = [1, 8]
in_3_lists = [2, 7]
in_2_lists = [4, 5]
in_1_list  = [3, 6]
```

If there are any duplicates in the original lists, it doesn't matter, only that the element is there.

What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 5):

Use a `collections.Counter` to get the counts of occurrences across lists, then accumulate back, eg:

```
counts = Counter(el for lst in (list1, list2, list3, list4) for el in set(lst))
```

Which gives you:

```
Counter({1: 4, 2: 3, 4: 2, 6: 1, 8: 4, 7: 3, 5: 2, 3: 1})
```

Then:

```
d = {}
for k, v in counts.items():
    d.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

Then `d` will be:

```
{4: [1, 8], 3: [2, 7], 2: [4, 5], 1: [6, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could easily use a combination of [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#counter-objects), like this:

```
from collections import Counter

l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['a', 'a', 'd']
l3 = ['a', 'd', 'e']
l4 = ['a', 'b', 'a']

c = Counter(set(l1))
c.update(set(l2))
c.update(set(l3))
c.update(set(l4))

print(c)  # >> Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'd': 2, 'c': 1, 'e': 1})
```

If you really want separated lists at the end, a possibility would be to use [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python), which is not the most perfmormant here, but yousaid your lists to be small so...:

```
   r1 = [item for item, count in c.items() if count == 1]
   r2 = [item for item, count in c.items() if count == 2]
   r3 = [item for item, count in c.items() if count == 3]
   r4 = [item for item, count in c.items() if count == 4]
```